# saving multiple arraylist to sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist

I retrieve some sensor values and store them to an ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<Float> x_event = new ArrayList<Float>();
ArrayList<Float> y_event = new ArrayList<Float>();
ArrayList<Float> z_event = new ArrayList<Float>();
```

In sensorChanged()

```
x_axis = acceleration[0];
y_axis= acceleration[1];
z_axis= acceleration[2];

x_event.add(x_axis);
y_event.add(y_axis);
z_event.add(z_axis);
```

Is there a way to save all ArrayList in one method to my SQLite database?

Comment: What is the real question?

Comment: Can I make a method in my Database handler which has parameters multiple arrayList? How to I loop the arraylist and save it to my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several ways to store this information on a DB. First that come to my mind are:

1. Create a table `event` with `index`, `x`, `y`, `z` columns. You iterate through the arrays and for index `i`, store in `event` `i`, `x_event.get(i)`, `y_event.get(i)`, `z_event.get(i)`.
2. Create a table `event_array_lists` with columns `id` and `arraylist`. [Serialize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html) the array lists and store them as a BLOB.
3. Convert the arraylists to [JSON](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html) and store them as strings in a very similar table than 2.